# Where can I find if a fixed blade knives is legal to carry around in a given country?

Tags: knives, legality

I am always uneasy at the idea of carrying around a fixed blade. For this reason, my backpack knife is a multitool (A fantastic Leatherman Blast, which saved the day already many times). I would like to know where I can find information and procedures to safely carry around a knife (if at all) when it comes to fixed blade, but also more in general for any kind of knife.

Answer (score 15):

Laws vary greatly by region, and are subject to being changed at any time. That being said, there are a few sites I used when looking up the knife laws in California.

**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife_legislation**
Provides a good overview of knife laws, but did not provide the specifics I need. It's worth browsing the sources that they reference however.

**http://knife-expert.com/sta-law.htm**
Seems to have a good summary of knife laws for each state.

**http://thefiringline.com/library/blades/knifelaws.html**
Very high level overview of state knife laws in a table, showing the concealed vs open carry status.

I wouldn't take any of these as fact, just as guidelines or resources to help you locate your official state / region's laws regarding knife laws.

Comment: This is the perfect answer IMO - pointing to helpful resources is the best we can do for legal quetions.